# Enable Location finder in android phone runtime using phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

How to enable location finder in automatically using `phonegap` or `cordova`.

I have one location search app, so user if can't on location in our mobile so automatically on that location finder.

Comment: See the "Hello, Cordova" app in the XDK demos and samples section (start a new project > samples and demos > html5+cordova > hello, cordova) for a complete example of using location.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.

Add this plugin to your cordova project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Then, use something like this:

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                             [geolocationError],
                                             [geolocationOptions]);

var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};
```

Comment: Let me know if his helped/answered.